# Пожалуйста, помогите: Юнити не запускается через Unity Hub

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android, unity3d-editor

Здраствуйте! Мучаюсь с unity уже третий-четвёртый день.

На голую виртуалку скачал unity hub. Потом и сам unity(2019.4.37f1). Запускаю проект(не создаю) и unity hub словно моргает(смотреть скрин ниже) и возвращается на тот момент, когда я нажал на кнопку проект( то есть до нажатия modified было три часа назад, после нажатия пара секунд, а уже когда моргнуло - опять три часа). В итоге же он не запускается. Создавать новый проект не пробовал + мне это не нужно

Попробовал вход через файл сцены - это работает, но почему-то выходит проблема `MethodAccessException: Requires team license`, но я думаю, что это связано с тем, что я открываю сцену через файл, потому что лицензия, сделанная в Unity Hub есть. Может сделать как-то лицензию в самом юнити? Проект лежит на D диске, я уверен, что дело не в нём т.к раньше таких проблем не было

Антивирус отключён. Раньше такой проблемы не было. Пробовал переустанавливать и версию unity и сам unity hub. Ошибки кстати тоже нету. Может посмотреть в логах?(Не знаю где они находятся). Огромная просьба - помогите пожалуйста. Я сам не справлюсь. Даже не представляю с чем это связано, а в гугле я ничего не нашёл

Программы находятся на диске C, а проекты на D
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня только два уточнения... 1)А Вам не поможет персональная лицензия, которую Юнити даёт всем желающим бесплатно? 2) не может ли проблема быть связана именнно с запуском в виртуалке - всё таки юнити штука довольно прожорливая, может, она не может как то DirectX'ом правильно пользоваться в виртуалке? Короче, Вы в виртуальной машине это в первый раз делаете?